# Is `template<typename>;` legal C++?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, grammar, declaration

[GCC](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UidGZkzQwCRHF60f) and [Clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gKsleDIFKkf4nlSX) disagree on whether `template<typename>;` is a valid statement in C++ at global scope.

I'd expect it not to be allowed in the C++ standard because templatization pertains to declaration statements, not to expression statements and in consequence also not to null statements (the statement `;`).

So, is this a bug in Clang?

Comment: It seems strange to me to use a semicolon when you are using template...

Comment: It's not valid C++ [according](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp) the standard. Clang is just being nice to you.

Comment: Well since both compilers emit a diagnostic, both are conforming.

Comment: @AntoineMorrier Templated class declarations and definitions always end in a semicolon.

Comment: @Sneftel Yes but it is not placed right after the `template<typename>`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not really. The standard explicitly disallows such a declaration in [[temp]p2](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#2);

> The *declaration* in a *template-declaration* (if any) shall
>
> - declare or define a function, a class, or a variable, or
> - define a member function, a member class, a member enumeration, or a static data member of a class template or of a class nested within a class template, or
> - define a member template of a class or class template, or
> - be a *deduction-guide*, or
> - be an *alias-declaration*.

An *empty-declaration* doesn't match any of those clauses. Now the standard says that an implementation is required to issue a diagnostic message for any violation of its rules, like this one. Note that it says *diagnostic*, it doesn't specify whether a warning or an error (or even a note) is issued. The compiler can provide extensions that make what you wrote valid, as it wouldn't change the meaning of a well-formed program.

So no, both are right. However, clang's behavior is due to an extension, not something that the standard specifies.

Comment: i wonder if such behavior on clang's part can break\change code's behavior where SFINAE is involved.

Comment: @Swift Nope. You cannot declare a template in the signature or in the template list. However, I would reasonably expect that clang ignores whatever extension it might have for SFINAE.

Comment: this "extension" relates to all declarations, not only to template ones, but I see what you're meaning.

Comment: How do we distinguish between a *null statement* and an *empty-declaration*? Is it so that only declarations may appear at global scope?

Comment: @Rakete1111 The standard defines *null statement*s in [stmt.expr]. *null statement*s are *expression statement*s whereas *empty-declaration*s are *declaration statement*s, so they're not the same thing. Yet, they both correspond to the same sequence of tokens: `;` So how do we classify a `;`?

Comment: @Fytch Oh I'm so sorry, I missed it. Ok so inside a compound statement there can only be a *declaration-statement*, which is a *block-declaration*. An *empty-declaration* is not a *block-declaration*.

Answer (score 14):

It's clang's idiosyncratic behavior that has existed for long time: missing declarations generate only a warning. It's just same as this:

```
int;
```

g++ would show an error, while clang will only show a warning. This doesn't contradict the standard.

> warning: declaration does not declare anything [-Wmissing-declarations]

`-Werror=missing-declarations` sets things straight.